# GET response is different from two sources

Tags: php, json, cookies, request, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to get a specific JSON response from a GET request, when I open chrome devtools is shows the correct Response, however when I try to do a GET request using Postman or PHP I do not get the same response. This might be due to the cookies.

Here is the URL I am requesting

```
http://services.runescape.com/m=website-data/playerDetails.ws?membership=false&names=[%22Lorie%22,%22NL%22,%22Jaimy%22,%22NL%20l%22,%22Maikel338%22,%22Libelle5%22,%22Sir%A0Vince%22,%22ZenaVuurwerk%22,%22troll%20mord%22,%22Mr%A0Prayer%22,%22Terror%A0elfje%22,%22terrorsmurf%22,%22Aboedja%22,%22Covariantie%22,%22Barypooter%22]&callback=jQuery172024342209566384554_1444939004634&_=1444939004888
```

The reponse I get is this;

```
`([{"isSuffix":false,"recruiting":true,"name":"Lorie","clan":"NL","title":"Miss"},{"isSuffix":false,"recruiting":true,"name":"NL","clan":"NL","title":""},{"isSuffix":false,"recruiting":true,"name":"Jaimy","clan":"NL","title":""},{"isSuffix":true,"recruiting":true,"name":"NL l","clan":"NL","title":"the Hot"},{"isSuffix":false,"recruiting":true,"name":"Maikel338","clan":"NL","title":"Vyrewatch"},{"isSuffix":false,"recruiting":true,"name":"Libelle5","clan":"NL","title":""},{"isSuffix":true,"recruiting":true,"name":"Sir Vince","clan":"NL","title":"the Handsome"},{"isSuffix":true,"recruiting":true,"name":"ZenaVuurwerk","clan":"NL","title":"the Quackers"},{"isSuffix":false,"recruiting":true,"name":"troll mord","clan":"NL","title":""},{"isSuffix":true,"recruiting":true,"name":"Mr Prayer","clan":"NL","title":"the Billionaire"},{"isSuffix":false,"recruiting":true,"name":"Terror elfje","clan":"NL","title":"The Famous"},{"isSuffix":false,"recruiting":true,"name":"terrorsmurf","clan":"NL","title":"Super"},{"isSuffix":false,"recruiting":true,"name":"Aboedja","clan":"NL","title":""},{"isSuffix":true,"recruiting":true,"name":"Covariantie","clan":"NL","title":"the Master"},{"isSuffix":false,"recruiting":true,"name":"Barypooter","clan":"NL","title":"Maxed"}]);`
```

However, when I open chrome devtools on the website that is requesting the same URL (http://services.runescape.com/m=clan-hiscores/members.ws?clanName=NL) and look for the same request to the API

It responds with this;

```
([{"isSuffix":false,"recruiting":true,"name":"Lorie","member":true,"clan":"NL","title":"Miss"},{"isSuffix":false,"recruiting":true,"name":"NL","member":false,"clan":"NL","title":""},{"isSuffix":false,"recruiting":true,"name":"Jaimy","member":true,"clan":"NL","title":""},{"isSuffix":true,"recruiting":true,"name":"NL l","member":false,"clan":"NL","title":"the Hot"},{"isSuffix":false,"recruiting":true,"name":"Maikel338","member":true,"clan":"NL","title":"Vyrewatch"},{"isSuffix":false,"recruiting":true,"name":"Libelle5","member":true,"clan":"NL","title":""},{"isSuffix":true,"recruiting":true,"name":"Sir Vince","member":true,"clan":"NL","title":"the Handsome"},{"isSuffix":true,"recruiting":true,"name":"ZenaVuurwerk","member":true,"clan":"NL","title":"the Quackers"},{"isSuffix":false,"recruiting":true,"name":"troll mord","member":true,"clan":"NL","title":""},{"isSuffix":true,"recruiting":true,"name":"Mr Prayer","member":true,"clan":"NL","title":"the Billionaire"},{"isSuffix":false,"recruiting":true,"name":"Terror elfje","member":false,"clan":"NL","title":"The Famous"},{"isSuffix":false,"recruiting":true,"name":"terrorsmurf","member":true,"clan":"NL","title":"Super"},{"isSuffix":false,"recruiting":true,"name":"Aboedja","member":true,"clan":"NL","title":""},{"isSuffix":true,"recruiting":true,"name":"Covariantie","member":true,"clan":"NL","title":"the Master"},{"isSuffix":false,"recruiting":true,"name":"Barypooter","member":true,"clan":"NL","title":"Maxed"}]);
```

As you can see, it also shows "member":true

This is the value I am looking for, however it only shows this on the website where I am trying to get it from, not from other GET Requests

Is this because of the cookies that are stored on the website? I just can't seem to figure out why it responds different. If any more information is needed, please say so.

Comment: I'm assuming that `member=true` means you are a member of the clan/guild/whatever? That likely relies on the user who is logged into the website. Without logging into the website with the user's username and password, there would be no way for the website to know if they are a member or not.

Comment: I am currently not logged in on the website and using Incognito, It means that you're a member (You're subscribed to the game), and it still shows the same result. So, you get the same response even when you're not logged in.

Comment: How are you making the GET request? cURL? get_file_content()?

Comment: When I copied and visited the page, I don't see `member=true`. I've never played runescape before.

Comment: Why don't you just look for the cookies in the request header?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Yeah, that's the problem, I am only able to see the member=true when I view the response in Chrome Devtools. Not when I view the URL or make a GET Request

Comment: @rjdown Even if I make a GET Request with the cookies it still shows the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while trying out things, I Figured out they only allowed it to be seen when the Host & Referrer header were the same as on their website where they requested it.

So, with the same Headers as they send I was able to get the same response.